# Why do we say this for triangles?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Case 1 ;Let us say there is a triangle $ABC$ and one $DEF$. If $AB = DE$ can we also say that $\angle BCA = \angle EFD $ ? What is the proof and reason for saying this ?

Case 2 : Supose $BC = EF$ along with  $AB=DE$.

Comment: Hmmm. I think if you fix one length in a triangle (in this case DEF), it doesn't say anything about the other two lengths. Therefore, we don't know anything about the angles in the triangle DEF. So I think this is false.

Comment: Ok.@MattiP. In case when two sides are equal.( BC=EF)?

Comment: I assume that (as usual in tha tcontext) "$=$" stands only for congruence (or equality in length) and not for identity?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh yes. My mistake

Comment: @TonyK It could be. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true for either case. Let's say $BC = EF = AB=DE$ (Which is a particular case of your conditions). We can choose the angles $\angle ABC$ and $\angle DEF$ at will, so we can make $ABC$ a right triangle at B (meaning $\angle ABC = 90º$) and $\angle DEF$=60º.

If you make the drawing you can clearly see that the two triangles are not equal and that their angles $\angle BCA$ and $\angle EFD$ are diferent. $\angle BCA$ = 45º (since it's a right isosceles triangle) and $\angle EFD$ = 60º (since an isosceles triangle with an angle of $60º$ between two equal sides will be equilateral).